# How to show that $Y_n = \sum_{i=1}^n Z_i$ is a martingale.

Tags: stochastic-processes, martingales

> Let $Z_i$ be independent rvs such that
> $$ P(Z_n = a_n) = \frac{1}{2n^2}, P(Z_n=0)=1-\frac{1}{n^2}, P(Z_n = -a_n) = \frac{1}{2n^2}$$
> where $a_1=2, a_n = 4\sum_{j=1}^{n-1}a_j $ for $n\ge 2$.
>
> 1. Show that $Y_n = \sum_{i=1}^n Z_i$ is a martingale.
> 2. Show that $Y=\lim Y_n$ exists almost surely, but that there exists no $M$ such that $E|Y_n∣\le M for all $n$.

- $Z$ is discrete and it's distribution is on the probability space so it must be an adapted process, and $Y$ is the sum of adapted processes meaning it is also adapted.
- It is integrable as each $a_j$ is finite.

I'm not sure if these two make sense, are they OK?

To show convergence:
By Martingale Convergence show that $\lim_{n\to\infty} \mathbb E(Y_{n+1}-Y_n)^2=0$. So if we condition on $Y_t$, we get
\begin{align*}
    \mathbb E\left((Y_{t+1}-Y_t)^2|Y_t\right)&=a_n\left(\frac{1}{2n^2}-Y_n\right)^2 + (1-a_n)\left(\frac{1}{2n^2}-Y_n\right)^2+ 0\left(\frac{1}{n^2}-Y_n\right)^2\\
    &=\left(\frac{1}{2n^2}-Y_n\right)^2\\
    &\ge 0
\end{align*}
Hence, by the tower property for expectations, we can deduce that
$$ \mathbb E\left((Y_{t+1}-Y_t)^2\right) = \mathbb{E}\left(\left(\frac{1}{2n^2}-Y_n\right)^2\right) = \frac{1}{2n^2}- \mathbb{E}((Y_n)^2) $$
Therefore,
$\lim_{n\to\infty} \mathbb E(Y_{n+1}-Y_n)^2=- \mathbb{E}((Y_\infty)^2)$

Comment: When you condition in $Z$ what exactly do you mean? What is this $Z$?

Comment: @DaviBarreira I mean $Z_t$ but as i want to show $Y_n$ has an a.s. limit it should be changed..

Comment: Are you sure this indeed converges? I've done some calculations, and I think $E|X_n| \rightarrow \infty$. So I cannot use the Convergence theorems that I normally use.

Comment: @DaviBarreira well the question in the book I'm reading says "Show that $Y = lim Y_n$ exists almost surely, but that there exists no $M$ such that $E\mid Y_n\mid \le M$ for all $n$

Comment: Ah, that's interesting... So perhaps one needs to use Borel-Cantelli. I will give it another try.

Comment: I complemented the answer. Now I think it solves what you were looking for. You should edit your original question with what you said in the comments, so readers can better understand what is being answers. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks a lot! Just to check, was my method for showing it converges on the right track? Maybe I got confused, I forgot about Borel-Cantelli :)

Comment: I don't know if your method would work :/ But glad I could help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps the reference you are consulting has a different definition, but as I understand, to show that $Y_n$ is Martingale, you have to show that:

i) $Y_n \in \mathcal F_n , \quad \forall n\in \mathbb N$;

ii) $E|Y_n|<\infty ,\quad \forall n \in \mathbb N$;

iii)$ E[Y_n \mid \mathcal F_{n-1}] = Y_{n-1}$.

Now, as you pointed out. The two initial properties can be trivially shown. Only the last one remains. Hence,

$$E[Y_n \mid \mathcal F_{n-1} ]= E[Z_n + Y_{n-1} \mid \mathcal F_{n-1}]=
 E[Z_n] - Y_{n-1}= Y_{n-1}
$$

Note that above we used the fact that $Z_n$ is independent and that $E[Z_n] = \frac{an}{2n^2} - 0(1-1/n^2) -\frac{an}{2n^2} =0$.

So $Y_n$ is a  martingale.

Finally, you asked in the comments to prove that $Y_n$ converges almost surely. We can prove this using Borel-Cantelli as follows:

If for any $\epsilon>0$, we have $\sum^\infty_{n=1}P(|Y_n|>\epsilon)<\infty$, then, $P(\lim_{n\to\infty}Y_n = 0)=1$

So, for any $\epsilon>0$, we note that
$$P(|Y_n| > \epsilon) \leq P(|Y_n| >0) = P(Y_n = a_n) + P(Y_n = -a_n) = \frac{1}{n^2}$$

Therefore,
$$
\sum^\infty_{n=1}P(|Y_n|>\epsilon)<\infty\implies Y_n \rightarrow_{a.s}0
$$

This concludes the proof.

Comment: Oh thank you and you're right, i got completely confused.. i meant to show almost sure convergence. I guess does my working make sense now?

Comment: Sorry, almost sure convergence in what sense? I mean, can you reformulate what exactly are you trying to prove? I left a comment on your solution. I didn't understand what you meant by $Z$ that you used to condition the expectation.